# Multiprocessing module messing up replacing Global Variable

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

So there is a global variable called 'someVariable' but somehow the variable does not change even though main function is called.
It looks like every time multiprocessing is called, it reruns the whole code again and assigns someVariable to fff again. How do I prevent it?

```
from multiprocessing import Process

print("someVariable set to fff")
someVariable = "fff"

def do_job():
    print("printing - " + someVariable)

def runTasks(totalProcesses):
    number_of_processes = int(totalProcesses)

    for w in range(number_of_processes):
        p = Process(target=do_job)
        p.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    someVariable = "lllllllllllllllllllll"
    runTasks(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider a couple of things:

- In `__main__` you have assigned:

  ```
  someVariable = "lllllllllllllllllllll"
  ```

  But this value is never passed to `do_job()` while printing.

---

### Solution

To change the variable you can:

- While declaring pass the desired text.

  ```
  p = Process(target=do_job, args=('lllllllllllllllllllll',))
  ```
- You need to invoke `join()` as well after `start()`:

  ```
  p.start()
  p.join()
  ```
- Your modified program will be:

  ```
  from multiprocessing import Process

  print("someVariable set to fff")
  someVariable = "fff"

  def do_job(string):
      print("printing - " + string)

  def runTasks(totalProcesses):
      number_of_processes = int(totalProcesses)

      for w in range(number_of_processes):
      p = Process(target=do_job, args=('lllllllllllllllllllll',))
      p.start()
      p.join()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      runTasks(3)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  someVariable set to fff
  someVariable set to fff
  printing - lllllllllllllllllllll
  someVariable set to fff
  printing - lllllllllllllllllllll
  someVariable set to fff
  printing - lllllllllllllllllllll
  ```

---

### Reference

[multiprocessing — Process-based parallelism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: But the 'llllllllllllllllll' would be user input value, not hardcoded. If we can't pass values from user, ermm...

Comment: @Pandoma Though in your question `someVariable` was a demo string, are you facing any issue to accept the string as an user input? Where are you stuck? Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement. SO contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: No, after user input, a print function right in main shows the variable is holding the value.

Comment: Instead of `'lllllllllllllllllllll'` pass the user input.

Comment: `someVariable = input("enter an input: ")` this replaces it but still the same result